# The type defined in the ABI is invalid?

Tags: cleos, abi

after  command

```
./cleos --url http://192.168.1.10:8888 system newaccount --stake-net "10.0000 SYS" --stake-cpu "10.0000 SYS" --buy-ram "10.0000 SYS"  eosio david EOS6XViVfWJjLNBkpyPKguP5N3X9Q48mcBezVCPFdkWetFDikNvfR EOS6jB1PPcit1t3b9jxMWtzRQ5fTRr1UBHEN67u8yWzPJTQJDUktE
```

I have

```
./cleos   --url http://192.168.1.10:8888  get account eosio
```

Error 3015004: The type defined in the ABI is invalid
Error Details:
Unknown struct voter_info

```
./cleos   --url http://192.168.1.10:8888  get account david
```

Error 3015004: The type defined in the ABI is invalid
Error Details:
Unknown struct user_resources

Comment: sounds like some of the `eosio.*` contracts are messed up. did you follow [this article](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence) and you made sure to use latest version?

Comment: I am using EOSIO 1.1.0 Release

Comment: that's quite old and contracts have been moved to [their own repo](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts) since then, but can't say for sure this is the cause of your problem